# writing data into file with binary packed format in python

Tags: python, file

I am reading some value for file and wants to write modified value into file. My file is .ktx format [binary packed format].

I am using struct.pack() but seems that something is going wrong with that:

```
bytes = file.read(4)
bytesAsInt = struct.unpack("l",bytes)
number=1+(bytesAsInt[0])
number=hex(number)
no=struct.pack("1",number)

outfile.write(no)
```

I want to write in both ways little-endian and big-endian.

Comment: what do you mean about little-endian and big-endian ... you only do one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
no_little =struct.pack(">1",bytesAsInt)
no_big =struct.pack("<1",bytesAsInt) # i think this is default ...
```

again you can check the docs and see the format characters you need 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

```
>>> struct.unpack("l","\x05\x04\x03\03")
(50529285,)
>>> struct.pack("l",50529285)
'\x05\x04\x03\x03'
>>> struct.pack("<l",50529285)
'\x05\x04\x03\x03'
>>> struct.pack(">l",50529285)
'\x03\x03\x04\x05'
```

also note that it is a lowercase `L` , not a one (as also covered in the docs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added these lines: no=struct.pack("<1",number) outfile.write(no) here number is my modified hex value which I want to write to file. now i get error "struct.error: pack requires exactly 0 arguments" with that code

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but the following function should solve your problem. At the moment it reads the file contents completely, creates a buffer and then writes out the updated contents. You could also modify the file buffer directly using `unpack_from` and `pack_into` but it might be slower (again, not tested). I'm using the `struct.Struct` class since you seem to want to unpack the same number many times.

```
import os
import struct

from StringIO import StringIO

def modify_values(in_file, out_file, increment=1, num_code="i", endian="<"):
    with open(in_file, "rb") as file_h:
        content = file_h.read()
    num = struct.Struct(endian + num_code)
    buf = StringIO()
    try:
        while len(content) >= num.size:
            value = num.unpack(content[:num.size])[0]
            value += increment
            buf.write(num.pack(value))
            content = content[num.size:]
    except Exception as err:
        # handle
    else:
        buf.seek(0)
        with open(out_file, "wb") as file_h:
            file_h.write(buf.read())
```

An alternative is to use the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) which makes it quite easy. I don't know how to implement endianess with an `array`.

```
def modify_values(filename, increment=1, num_code="i"):
    with open(filename, "rb") as file_h:
        arr = array("i", file_h.read())
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] += increment
    with open(filename, "wb") as file_h:
        arr.tofile(file_h)
```